# How do I make a inline-block div occupy the rest of the space

Tags: html, css

I have a link and an inline div next to it (to the right).  I want the div to occupy the rest of the space to the right.  Is there a way to do that?

```
<a href="#">what</a><div style="display:inline-block;width:200px;border:1px solid red">hello</div>
```

Comment: No, it moves the div to the next line.  I can use a table to do this.

Comment: Why don't you move the `a` inside the `div`?

Comment: Can't you use a margin-right: 0 or right: 0?

Comment: I suppose I could do that.

Comment: no, wait, did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap a span around the div, like:

```
<a href="#">what</a><span><div>hello</div></span>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6d3qX/)**

You can apply this CSS to get what you're after:

```
a {
    background: #ccc;
    float: left
}
span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4px 0 6px
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap everything within a div and give it table and table cell to children:

http://jsfiddle.net/T4Qcd/

```
.inner{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}

a{
    display:table-cell;
}

.wrapper{
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by applying width to both anchor tag as well as the div.

```
a{
   width:10%;
}
div{
   width:90%;
}
```

Your html would be.

```
<a href="#">what</a>
<div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red">hello</div>
```